# How to install static libz.dll.a,libssl.dll.a, etc on MinGW/MSYS2?

Tags: windows, dll, cmake, mingw, msys2

I'm getting this on my project's linking process (compiles with cmake):

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable roosek2.exe
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/9.1.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: cannot find -lC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libz.dll.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/9.1.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: cannot find -lC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libssl.dll.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/9.1.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: cannot find -lC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libcrypto.dll.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/9.1.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: cannot find -lC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libzstd.dll.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/roosek2.dir/build.make:578: roosek2.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/LZ/roosek_ocr2'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:77: CMakeFiles/roosek2.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/LZ/roosek_ocr2'
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

This happens when I compile with static qt5 from MSYS2 in MinGW shell. Here's my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(roosek2 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)


find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)

add_executable(roosek2
  main.cpp
  qml.qrc
  ImageStream.cpp
  YuvUtils.cpp
  CameraView.cpp
)

add_library(ctmedia_codec MODULE IMPORTED)
add_library(ctstream MODULE IMPORTED)
add_library(maincore MODULE IMPORTED)

#link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/win_bin/lib/x64)
set_target_properties(ctmedia_codec PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/win_bin/lib/x64/CTMedia.lib)
set_target_properties(ctstream PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/win_bin/lib/x64/CTStream.lib)
set_target_properties(maincore PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/win_bin/lib/x64/WPMainCore.lib)

include_directories("include")
target_compile_definitions(roosek2
  PRIVATE $<$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>:QT_QML_DEBUG>)
target_link_libraries(roosek2
  PRIVATE Qt5::Core Qt5::Quick ctmedia_codec ctstream maincore)
```

How do I install these libraries? Why are they being required? Do I really need them?

Comment: why did you import some `.lib` (x64/CTStream.lib) ? I suspect them to depend on your missing archive files

Answer (score 0):

Install these packages:

- For X86_64 (64 bit):

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib mingw-w64-x86_64-zstd
```

- For X86 (32 bit):

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-openssl mingw-w64-i686-zlib mingw-w64-i686-zstd
```